# Is it possible to display a string formatted table in a javaFx label?

Tags: java, javafx

```
public static void printDetails() {
    //PRINTING DEFAULT MEMBERS NAMES AS AN ARRAY

    int i;
    System.out.println ("  ");
    System.out.printf ("%-20s%-20s%-25s%-25s%-25s%n", "Index", "Name", "membershipDate",
            "membershipNumber","member type");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------")

    for (i = 0; i < defaultNames.size (); i++) {
        System.out.format ("%-20s%-20s%-25s%-25s%-25s%n", i + 1, defaultNames.get (I),
                defaultMembershipDate.get (i), defaultMembershipNumber.get (i),defaultMemberType.get (i));
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Why? Why not display it in a `TableView`? But, sure, you could do this: just concatenate all that into a single `String` with newlines, and set it as the label's text. You probably want to set the label's font to a monospaced font as well.

Comment: You may also want to think about creating a membership object as well to easier track all of the membership data

Comment: @James_D thank you for your response..ive made 4 arraylists and could you tell me how to add the user  content to the table?

Comment: @James_D   //----ARRAY LISTS TO STORE USER INPUTS-----------
    static ArrayList<String> defaultNames = new ArrayList<String> ();
    static ArrayList<Integer> defaultMembershipNumber = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    static ArrayList<String> defaultMembershipDate = new ArrayList<String> ();
    static ArrayList<String> defaultMemberType = new ArrayList<String> ();

Comment: As @Matt says, make a class to represent each row in the table, then just do exactly as in the [`TableView` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html), or see any [tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part2/)

Comment: @James_D will do! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to display a string formatted table in a javaFx label but it will not look very nice as James_D said you should use a `TableView` it will look much cleaner and it will help keep you code cleaner as well instead of using 4 different `ArrayList`s you will end up have 1 `ArrayList` with objects containing their own data from there you can pass those objects to the `TableView` and let it handle the work for you

In the future/when your coding this for whatever you are working on you should update the `MembershipData` to the correct data types for example you could change `startDate` to be `LocalDate` and obviously change the Number to be an `Integer`

It would end up looking something like this

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ArrayList<MembershipData> membershipDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf((char) (i + 64));
            membershipDataArrayList.add(new MembershipData(letter, ""+i+i+i, ""+i+i+i, letter));
        }

        showDetails(membershipDataArrayList);
    }

    public void showDetails(ArrayList<MembershipData> membershipDataArrayList) {

        System.out.println ("  ");
        System.out.printf ("%-20s%-20s%-25s%-25s%-25s%n", "Index", "Name", "membershipDate",
                "membershipNumber","member type");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");

        int i = 0;
        for (MembershipData membershipData : membershipDataArrayList) {
            System.out.format ("%-20s%-20s%-25s%-25s%-25s%n", i++, membershipData.getName(),
                    membershipData.getStartDate(), membershipData.getNumber() ,membershipData.getType());
        }

        TableColumn<MembershipData, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TableColumn<MembershipData, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("MemberShip Date");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startDate"));

        TableColumn<MembershipData, String> column3 = new TableColumn<>("MemberShip Number");
        column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("number"));

        TableColumn<MembershipData, String> column4 = new TableColumn<>("MemberShip Type");
        column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("type"));

        TableView<MembershipData> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(column1, column2, column3, column4);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(membershipDataArrayList);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(tableView);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Stage stage  = new Stage();
        stage.setWidth(475);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is what your membership class would look like

```
public class MembershipData{
    private final String name;
    private final String startDate;
    private final String number;
    private final String type;

    public MembershipData(String name, String startDate, String number, String type){
        this.name = name;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you want a `TableView<MembershipData>` and the columns should be `TableColumn<MembershipData, String>` (or `Number`, `LocalDate` for the second parameter, as appropriate)..

Comment: Yeah your right for the `TableView<MembershipData>` and the `TableColumn<MembershipData, String> ` as for everything else it was more of an example to get him started which is why its coded as it is but I should mention that in the post which is my bad